# How to handle invalid value exception in haskell and keep running

Tags: haskell, exception, io

I'm trying to implement this excersive, but in Haskell

> Write a higher-order function called transform that applies the same
>   function to all elements of a list transforming it to the new values. 
>   However, if an exception occurs when transforming an element of the
>   list, the original value in the given list should be used. For
>   instance
>
> - transform (fn x => 15 div x) [1,3,0,5] -------------------- val it = [15,5,0,3] : int list

I'm really confused when it comes to exception handling in haskell, I don't get it.
I have this base code I've written, but it must be adapted to work with the exception handler.

```
import Control.Exception
import System.Environment  
import System.IO

data MyError = Error deriving Show
Instance Exception MyError

transform :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] 
transform f [] = []
transform f (x:xs)  = [f x] ++ transform f [xs]
```

I have several questions as to how to throw and catch this particular exception so that the program will not stop its processing chain because of it.

I have read the documentation, that says:

> If you want to do some cleanup in the event that an exception is
>   raised, use finally, bracket or onException. To recover after an
>   exception and do something else, the best choice is to use one of the
>   try family. ... unless you are recovering from an asynchronous
>   exception, in which case use catch or catchJust.

So I'm guessing my best choice would be maybe to use a try or a catch statement?
But I'm not really sure how to write/organize it.

I'm really new to functional programming, all help to understand this issue better is very much appreciated.

Comment: Where did that exercise come from? What it's asking you to do isn't really something you should do in Haskell.

Comment: Its an excercise taken from the book Foundations of Programming Languages, second edition, chapter 5 (the one dedicated to functional languages). Just that it was intended for standard ML and we were asked to use haskell instead

Comment: Does the type have to be `(a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`, or can it be `(a -> a) -> [a] -> IO [a]` at least instead?

Comment: By the way, if your division-by-zero happens, the error that Haskell will throw won't be your `MyError` type.

Comment: It must be! I just hadn't realized it yet in my confused state

Comment: That's what's really confusing me, because according to the given function that the user inputs to "transform" the error could be any possible type, right? ahhh

Comment: I don’t know how Standard ML does it, but a common way to encapsulate errors in Haskell is to use the `Maybe` type. You’d make your function `transform :: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]` and its first argument would indicate an “exception” by returning `Nothing`. This way you wouldn’t have to have it be in `IO`, since most “exceptions” can be thrown and handled without `IO` using something like `Maybe` (it might be a worthwhile exercise to write a function `safeDiv :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int` which returns `Nothing` when `div` would error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're being asked to do isn't something that you should do. If I really had to write a function that handles exceptions for some reason without being in IO, though, I'd install [`spoon`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1) and then write this:

```
import Control.Spoon (teaspoon)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

transform :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
transform f = map $ \x -> fromMaybe x . teaspoon $ f x
```

Without third-party libraries, you could write this instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Exception (catch, evaluate, SomeException)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

transform :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
transform f = map $ \x -> unsafePerformIO $ evaluate (f x) `catch` \(_ :: SomeException) -> pure x
```

For emphasis: I would be unhappy to ever see either of these done in production, mainly due to `unsafePerformIO` (which `teaspoon` uses internally). However, if you were allowed to put the result in `IO`, then the second solution, but without `unsafePerformIO`, would be acceptable (although catching asynchronous exceptions is also bad, so you'd want something more nuanced than `SomeException`).

Comment: I will study this alternative, right away! Thank you very much.